# Block popup from iframe without using sandbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For personal use, I want to block popup coming from 3rd part iframe website. I tried to use sandbox but if it's working for some, most of embedded websites block the video when the iframe is sandboxed.
Is there an alternative way ? I can't use browser extension.

With sandbox (the embedded websites block the read)

```html
<iframe src="https://doodstream.com/e/ouwwyxd8yu4u" sandbox = "allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

The embedded website checks if I use sandbox so I can't use sandbox to block "popup".

Without sandbox, too many popups from the embedded websites.

```html
<iframe src="https://doodstream.com/e/ouwwyxd8yu4u" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: You can't do anything to the iframe content with scripting from your page, because its content is from a different origin. _'The embedded website checks if I use sandbox so I can't use sandbox to block "popup".'_ - probably a good indicator that they would not want you to use their content in the way you are attempting to do, in the first place.

Comment: Did u find any solution?

Comment: no sorry, I didn't find any solution